# Passing a static HTML form data to an ASPX file

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

Hoping you can help. I've hit a snag with my company website. My experience is in HTML, CSS and PHP. All server scripting I've done is in PHP. However, an internal policy here is that we can't use PHP on the site.

My issue is, that our site has a contact form, it's well laid out, well validated, responsive, tooltipped, etc, but I need to process the form submission into an email. Normally I'd do this using PHP but as mentioned above, that's not an option.

All I want to do as proof of concept is to read in the form data using ASP. Once I've done this and proved all of the data is being read in from the form, I'll then work on passing the values off to our SMTP client.

So, I've very little experience in ASP and I'm hoping you guys can help dig me out of a hole.

How can I pass the details from my contact form to ASP? I've tried googling it and working from other peoples examples but I'm struggling and it's perhaps because I'm working on answers from a different question.

Comment: What framework you use, how do you post you data to server side, etc, You can to provide more information to get correct answer here!

Answer (score 1):

For a sample HTML form :

```
<form method="POST" action="send_email.aspx">
    <div>
        Input 1: <input type="text" name="inputFieldName1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Input 2: <input type="text" name="inputFieldName2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Create a new text file `send_email.aspx` and add this content :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">   
    public void Page_Load( Object sender, EventArgs E )
    {       
        // Here you get the input values, equivalent to $_POST["inputFieldName1"]/$_GET["inputFieldName1"], etc...
        string inputFieldValue1 = ""+Request["inputFieldName1"];
        string inputFieldValue2 = ""+Request["inputFieldName2"];

        // this part is taken from @hrvoje-hudo response, thanks to him !
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-server-host");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("from@domain.com");

        mail.To.Add("to@domain.com");

        mail.Subject = "The subject";

        // Here you define your message
        mail.Body = "Hello,\n";
        mail.Body += "Input1 = " + inputFieldValue1 + "\n";
        mail.Body += "Input2 = " + inputFieldValue2 + "\n";

        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.Send(mail);

    }
</script>
```

Configure the input list, server host, email from/to, message and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

When you receive form data with POST method, you can just use SmtpClient to send an email:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp server");

mail.From = new MailAddress("some_email@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("to address");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "Body";

client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

client.Send(mail);
```